# Why am I getting inconsistent results from Spark rdd.count()?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Code is below.  If i run it multiple times, the difference in the two rdd.count() calls changes.  I was under the impression rdd.filter(func) should not affect the original rdd.

```
print(rdd.count())
    8105
print(rdd.filter(lambda d: d['label'] == 1).count())
    3528
print(rdd.count())
    8099
```

So..., building off the comments below, this rdd was created with a randomSplit().  RandomSplit() is a lazy transformation which gets recomputed on each action, e.g. count().  Zero323 suggested adding a seed would get rid of the nondeterminism in my results.  However, I added one (and was not able to find any other uses of any random function) with no affect, so the problem remains open.

Comment: Some context would be useful. If we don't know how you create `rdd` there is no way to tell how it happens.

Comment: it's 1000+ lines of code.  it starts with some relational table dumps.  it does data cleaning, aggregations, joins, disaggregation, a random split, and some nlp processing before it gets to this point.

Comment: Here you are - _a random split_.

Comment: Ok, it's plausible it's related. But what's going on?

Comment: If you have a random split without fixed seed and data is not cached you get new split on every action. Nothing unexpected about it.